# What is the difference between Anaconda R and R from the R Foundation?

Tags: r, anaconda, miniconda

We are looking at using the R Anaconda (Minicoda 3) provides vs the R the R Foundation provides. Does anyone know the differences or can point to a document(s) that lists the differences?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Anaconda R uses dynamic linking vs regular R Project R uses static linking.
Anaconda R is also checked for malware and R Project R is not. There might be commercial R that is checked for malware.